# How to display cmake build colors in gvim

Tags: vim, cmake

I am using cmake for my project, and I find the ouput of the processing build in bash is quite clear: build lines are green, linking are red, echos are white. It facilitates the reading a lot.

When I launch `:make` from gvim, I don't have any output colors. I don't understand where the problem comes from: must I set a parameter in quickfix or in cmake?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, it's problem of vim, not CMake.

Comment: @arrowdodger not necessarily. Not knowing `cmake`'s case in particular, but some colour-outputting apps will drop colours if they detect a dumb terminal or a pipe. On the other hand, I don't believe that vim will parse ANSI colour codes just like that.

Comment: My mistake, I was talking about gvim, and not vim! Actually it seems to be a gvim problem, the builtin_gui is a dumb terminal which does not handle much, and certainly not ANSI colors: http://superuser.com/questions/309883/how-do-i-declare-the-terminal-type-in-vim-so-that-make-can-output-colours

Answer (score 1):

GVIM only uses a minimalistic, pretty dumb terminal emulation. It does not understand ANSI color sequences.

For many commands, you can turn off the color output via a `--no-color` or `--color=never` argument.